# Incremental upper bound in sorted range

Tags: c++, search, binary-search

Since initial question [Increasing binary search for mismatch in sorted range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77874553/increasing-binary-search-for-mismatch-in-sorted-range) contained defects in code and can confuse the readers, here is the updated version of the question.

Is the code below correct and efficiently implemented to solve the following task? Can this code be improved with reuse of other C++ Standard Library algorithms without additional libraries?

**Functional specification**

Having a very large vector (gigabytes) with sorted repeated values with exponential distribution (like 50% of values occur only once, 25% only two times in a row, 12.5% about 3 times in a row, etc.) provide a function to get iterator to the next value (different than current) in `std::vector`.

The algorithm is going to be used with many predicates for the same vector of data.

Performance is key both from perspective CPU loading and memory bandwidth. Actual values in the vector are not integers and comparison is time-consuming operation, so using std::upper_bound is not effective here, since it involves about log2(n) comparisons while the needed element often is very close.

**Design**

Having requirements on limited data bandwidth and having many predicates for the same data prevents us from pre-calculating offsets to needed positions.

Based on values frequency distribution, it is more effective to start with range 1 and multiply the range with every step, this gives about 30% of speed up against pure [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) usage.

**The code**

The fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zq657853j):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Algorithm works similarly to std::upper_bound, but uses element specified by iterator *first* to find first element in range which is not equal to it.
template<class RandomIt, class Pred>
constexpr RandomIt incremental_upper_bound(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Pred comp, size_t starting_search_range = 1)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    const auto current = *first++;

    size_t short_search_range = starting_search_range;

    while (first != last) {
        const auto short_search_end = (size_t)std::distance(first, last) < short_search_range ? last : std::next(first, short_search_range);

        first = std::upper_bound(first, short_search_end, current, comp);

        if (first == last || comp(current, *first))
            return first;

        short_search_range *= 2;
    }

    return last;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7 };

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ) {
        auto it_next = incremental_upper_bound(it, v.end());

        std::cout << "Number of elements with value " << *it << " is " << it_next - it << "\n";
        // Some work on the range

        it = it_next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Measurements**

Per advice from *G. Sliepen* I’ve done some measurements in terms of number of comparisons and performance. To show the trends, I tested on tiny, medium and large text bases.

The suffix arrays for real texts have some specifics, the next unique element comes very fast (example for 9 lexems long strings limit for comparison), so real offsets statistics are like this:

| Offset | Amount in data | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 463682831 | 98.49% |
| 2 | 6519364 | 1.38% |
| 3 | 400000 | 0.08% |
| 4 | 124922 | 0.03% |
| 5 | 18276 | 0.00% |
| 6 | 8421 | 0.00% |
| 7 | 5086 | 0.00% |
| 8 | 2802 | 0.00% |
| 9 | 1941 | 0.00% |
| 10 | 1727 | 0.00% |

Here are the results:

|  | std::upper_bound | incremental_upper_bound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Tiny text** (text size: 363 lexems; dictionary size: 153 lexems |  |  |
| Amount of comparisons (predicate calls) | 1943 | 551 |
| **Medium size text** (text size: 69 910 995 lexems; dictionary size: 878 993 lexems) |  |  |
| Amount of comparisons (predicate calls) | 1 428 018 106 | 115 013 024 |
| Running time, seconds | 33 | 7 |
| **Large text** (text size: 583 654 363 lexems; dictionary size: 2 791 370 lexems) |  |  |
| Amount of comparisons (predicate calls) | 13 122 916 104 | 943 337 060 |
| Running time, seconds | 436 | 79 |

**Conclusion**

The results are as expected. Let’s see the last case. For the index array std:upper_bound needs about 28 iterations on average to find the answer and incremental_upper_bound takes two on average, so the comparisons rate in about 14 times.

Of course, this is the data specifics which makes the improvement so huge. When we mostly need to find the next unique elements in one or two positions from current, it is different from other datasets. But, anyway, on large data std:upper_bound is memory-bounded and not cache-friendly, making huge steps could be quite expensive for such task as "searching for the next element, not equal to current". The *incremental_upper_bound* helps to localize work and increase caching benefits.

Comment: Your `main` example suggests an ordered [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) datastructure, of either `(val, len)` or `(val, index)` tuples. If your (unseen) values are K-tuples, with K predicates defined on them, then just produce K datastructures to assist with navigating a DB cursor over them. This is what happens when you CREATE TABLE with K columns, and then K times issue a CREATE INDEX command, in order to support rapid GROUP BY queries.

Comment: @J_H, as it is stated in the functional specification, the algorithm is memory-bound. Having many predicates, I will have to create many pairs (val,len) for every predicate. Taking into account that the vector takes gigabytes, these indexes will take even more gigabytes and performance will decrease dramatically. I tried this and the result is quite memory-consuming and slow. Let's assume here that we don't have a luxury of preprocessing.

Comment: By hypothesis the first half of your N values consuming "gigabytes" will fit in a single RLE entry, then 0.25 × N for the second entry, then 0.125 × N for the third entry. At some point we encounter diminishing returns, and resort to using the underlying values rather than an ancillary compressed representation of them. So the RLE entries consume small amount of RAM, even after expanding that by your undisclosed K multiplier. // You haven't given any throughput or latency performance targets. When sqlite stores indexed values on disk, most remain there. It's unclear why RAM residency is needed

Comment: @J_H,  Please note "like 50% of values occur only once". This is key which ruins the RLE approach application here, isn't it? In the best case I could have 20 different predicates each of which will give at least 3/4 of vector size RLE entries.

Comment: @J_H, I really don't know how to balance here between being concise in the question and providing long source code. In this particular case as stated in the question "actual values in the vector are not integers", it contains pointers to entries in the text database. When the predicate works it compares pointed strings based on some conditions in the predicate. The entries equal with one predicate won't be equal with another, although sorting is kept. So, for each predicate you will need huge amount of keys.

Comment: So now we know there's twenty columns, K=20, thank you for revealing that hidden fact. It would be helpful if you revealed details of the _actual_ problem you're working on. Full Text Search is largely a solved problem, well addressed by [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) and others. "I have big dataset and small RAM" is also a solved problem, well addressed by key-value stores, RDBMS, NoSQL, redis Bloom filters and others. Absent numbers, such as a query throughput target, it's hard to evaluate whether we've made solid engineering tradeoffs or not.

Comment: @J_H, don't the sentences "The algorithm is going to be used with many predicates for the same vector of data." and "Having requirements on limited data bandwidth and having many predicates for the same data prevents us from pre-calculating offsets to needed positions." from original question cover this? If not, could you please help me in wording.

Comment: @J_H, I agree, having the full problem on the table, would be more beneficial. I will post in as another code review request when I'll be able to make is small enough to post here. Real code takes hundreds of lines, so I am not sure how to post it here and without the code it is hard to explain the exact task. At the moment, let's consider this code "as is" taking as precondition that we don't have a luxury to spend more memory or do some significant preprocessing. Would it work?

Comment: @J_H, at the end of the day, let's be consistent here. Nobody suggests to authors of C++ Standard Library to implement std::upper_bound with RLE, preprocessing, memory allocation, etc. and my function is just an extension for existing algorithm; why should it be treated so differently?

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw, I rolled back the renaming `current` to `value`. Other points were never mentioned by the reviewer, so they don't affect the answer. I suggest keeping these changes, since they help to avoid excessive discussion on the code.

Comment: Your description mentions that the chance of \$n + 1\$ repetitions is half of \$n\$ repetitions, but your data shows the chance drops off much faster than that. So maybe a linear search might be even faster and simpler?

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I had the same thoughts when got this data, but the largest offset I see in real data is 276880 and the key point is that this could vary from text to text, so it is still possible to have dozens of large offsets for huge text files and this will lead linear search to disaster. My original code had explicit check of offset==1, but I decided to simplify the code relying to inlining both incremental_upper_bound and called from in std::upper_bound so case of offset==1 should be processed fast enough. I still can check explicitly in incremental_upper_bound if I see speed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `current` should be a reference

If comparisons are time-consuming, then the values you are comparing are probably non-trivial. Your declaration of `current` makes a copy of a value, which can be expensive, or perhaps even impossible if the value type of the container is non-copyable. Making `current` a reference solves this.

## Measure how many comparisons it actually takes

According to cppreference.com, `std::upper_bound()` uses at most \$\log_2(last - first) + O(1)\$ comparisons. However, the actual number of comparisons depends on the exact implementation of the standard library, and where in the range you pass it the upper bound really is. For example, there is no guarantee that it does its first comparison with the last element in the range.

So I would create a `class` with a comparison operator that counts how often it is called. Then you can call your `incremental_upper_bound()` on a vector with the desired distribution, and check how many comparisons it takes. Then you can also check if different ways to initialize and update `short_search_range` are better or worse.

It might also make sense to avoid using `std::upper_bound()`, and do the search yourself. That way you have full control of when comparisons are made.

Comment: On the making `current` a reference. In my case the vector stores int values which represent offsets in suffix array which is used to compare the pointed substrings; that's why comparison is time-consuming; at the same time the value stored in the vector is a pure `unsigned int` (not size_t to save memory so far tests sets don't exceed 4 Gb). So, at the moment `current` is copyable and copying is not time consuming, but planning to make algorithm generic it is better to reduce requirements to data; so reference is better and optimizer will do its work on caching; is this understanding correct?

Comment: On the amount of comparisons, I measured on 3Gb text and with my algorithm the function that uses it to find equal strings works 30% faster. Not sure home much faster the algorithm itself, maybe even more if other processing in function takes time. Won't it be "too much" or "overfocusing" to make extra measurements? Is it worth to avoid reuse of `std::upper_bound` when it works fast enough with my addition (on my data)? I remember how many years it took for programmers (back in 1960-70th) to get first correct version of binary search function...

Comment: A reference is for sure better for large types. And since the call to `std::upper_bound()` will very likely be inlined, the compiler can optimize things and effectively pass `current` to it by value. The issue with `std::upper_bound()` is that there is no guarantee what value it will pick for its first comparison. The first element in the range? Something in the middle? Maybe the last element? What would be better for your situation"? You like the 30% increase in efficiency, but what if it could be 50%?

Comment: I can't think of implementation which could work differently than pure binary search for random access iterators; I just checked the VS 2024 implementation, it runs classic binary search. And in the vast majority of cases the range for `std::upper_bound` will be way too small for any data specific-optimizations. Anyway, I will do research here as homework for practice. (And,of course, it doesn't start with comparison with "*the last element in the range*", it starts comparison with the element in the middle to decide where to continue the search, in the first or the second part of the range. )

Comment: The **Meausrements** and **Conclusions** sections have been added, Please see the results. In my case data specifics shows directly that I should start with `starting_search_range=1`. The multiplier under the question still, it could be improved based on data specifics, but this will take significant work and give less benefits. So, since this won't be an easy taken fruit, let's stay with 2.

Comment: Found two subtle defects meanwhile: (1) `*first != current`, of course is wrong with the version with predicate and had been replaced with `comp(value, *first)`; (2) Version with predicate can't have default functors for predicate (at least, can't have those I had); fixed.